# How do you make a div with a set max-height resize itself from the bottom when content is removed?

Tags: css, reactjs

I've got a modal that contains a bunch of list items that allow for a user to click a button and remove them. There is a `min-height` and a `max-height` on the container. When the max height is met, the list becomes scrollable. Once I start to remove the items and the content no longer takes up enough space to reach the max height, the div shrinks, but it shrinks equally from the top and the bottom. I only want it to shrink upwards from the bottom so that the top of the modal stays in the same place. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps vertically align to the top of the container/page.

That or absolute positioning.